# rxjs: Map adding field

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm looking for a more elegant way to write that code:

```
Observable.of(
        {field: "title"},
        {field: "referenceId", key: "refid"},
        {field: "app"},
        {field: "user"},
        {field: "action"},
        {field: "expiresAt", key: "expiration"},
        {field: "timestamp"}
    )
    .pipe(
        map(field => {
            if (!field.key) {
                return { ...field, key: field.field, sorteable: true };
            }
            else {
                return { ...field, sorteable: true };
            }
        })
    );
```

Comment: return { ...field, sorteable: true } in both cases? Is that right?

Comment: Sorry, I've changed code.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the ternary conditional operator [?](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/ternary-conditional-operator-in-typescript/) like this:

```
    .pipe(
        map(field => 
          field.key ? { ...field, sorteable: true } : { ...field, key: field.field, sorteable: true }
    );
```

You could also just simplify your code by omitting the else condition:

```
    .pipe(
        map(field => {
          let temp = { ...field, sorteable: true }
          if(!field.key) {
            temp = {...temp, key: field.field}
          }
          return temp
        }
    );
```

You could even combine both solutions:

```
    .pipe(
        map(field => {
          let temp = { ...field, sorteable: true }
          return field.key ? temp : {...temp, key: field.field}
        }
    );
```